# Freecam in DoTA 2

Tags: dota-2

I'm trying to take a good look at my DoTA 2 gear (on the characters) and I seem to be unable to get freecam working...
The thing about Hero Ground Chase is that you can't see UNDERNEATH the character without the camera annoyingly clipping on the ground.

Is there any way to make a freecam that is pretty much like a first-person game, only that it is flying (like the "fc" command in Skyrim)?

Basically, a freecam where you move with the arrow keys and rotate with the mouse... Similar to Skyrim's WASD and mouse freecam movement.

Comment: try this command: **cam_collision 0** "When in thirdperson and cam_collision is set to 1, an attempt is made to keep the camera from passing though walls. "

Comment: Furthermore you should activate cheats with **sv_cheats 1** and use **noclip 1** to have free movement. But I do not know how to move in that view

Comment: What I meant was to make the camera behave like the freecam in Skyrim (except of course not using WASD as controls... Unless it actually uses WASD as controls).

Comment: based on this video (since i did not play sky for long): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vU4coDV3uo4 it does the same with the commands I presented. You get a free camera that you can move around (not sure how).